# Comment with email or social networks

Tags: users, 7, comments

I am developing my personal site in drupal 7. Actually i am searching for a module which allows anonymous users commenting with their email or any social n/w like twitter,facebook or google+. Is there any good module available or is drupal 7 supports  anonymous users commenting with their email address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve that using the [Disqus](https://www.drupal.org/project/disqus) module

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the [OpenID Selector](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_selector) module

> This module integrates [Javascript OpenID Selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) with Drupal's OpenID client.
>
> This module substitutes Drupal's default OpenID form with Javascript OpenID Selector widget, so users do not even need to know what OpenID URL is.

Comment: Thanks, with this module first user has to register & then do comment ?
Because i dont want users to register & do commenting